# Sum two Dynamic Arrays

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I'm doing a homework problem where I have two take input from a user in the form of two dynamic `char` arrays (max of 100 characters each) and returning their sum.

I'm struggling with coming up with a sum function that works correctly when the two numbers are of different length or when the answer is less than 100 digits. When the numbers are of different length, they get added as if they were the same (e.g. 100 + 1000 becomes 1000+1000). When the result is less than 100 digits, the full arrays is printed anyway (so there are dozens of trailing zeros). (EDIT: Fixed, see below).

I know that there is no way to tell the actual size of a dynamic array, and I can't figure out any way to place some sort of sentinel value that stops the program from processing farther. I'm not allowed to use vectors or traditional arrays, which would give me a clear path to the solution. EDIT: This has been fixed by checking for '\0'.

I know SO doesn't want to do people's homework for them (nor am I asking that), but I do need some guidance as to how I can solve this problem. I've been working for hours and still can't think of a solution.

My program is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int* sum(char*, char*);

int main() {
    char * arr = new char[100];
    char * arr2 = new char[100];
    std::cout << "Enter value 1: ";
    std::cin >> arr;
    std::cout << "Enter value 2: ";
    std::cin >> arr2;
    int * result = sum(arr, arr2);
    std::cout << "Result: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 && result[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        std::cout << result[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int* sum(char * num1, char* num2) {
    std::reverse(num1, num1 + 100);
    std::reverse(num2, num2 + 100);
    bool carryOver = false;
    int* retarr = new int[100]; //Array to return to user
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          //Numerical value is char - 48, unless
          //char value is zero, then int val is zero
          int val1 = std::max(num1[i] - 48, 0);
          int val2 = std::max(num2[i] - 48, 0);
          int carry = (carryOver)? 1 : 0;
          carryOver = false; //Reset carryOver var
          int t = val1 + val2 + carry;
          if (t >= 10) {
              t = t % 10;
              carryOver = true;
          }
          retarr[99 - i] = t;
    }
    return retarr;
}
```

Comment: These are standard "C" NUL-terminated strings, so the sentinel value is the NUL character (`'\0'` or just `0`).

Comment: Note that your `std::reverse` isn't respecting the end of the string.   `strlen` may help here.

Comment: @BenVoigt Excellent! I'll update the code to reflect this